# memory increase while using jax.value_and_grad

Tags: jax, flax

I'm using jax and flax.
My problem is RAM increase while using jax.value_and_grad(loss_fn, has_aux=True).
about 8MB increase
So process go down before end of learning.
Is there any solution?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question does not have enough detail to allow for a good answer. It would help if you included a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you are running. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more general tips.